# Laravel storeAs() images in storage issue

Tags: laravel, image, storage

I'm having a problem uploading images to a specific folder inside one of my Laravel storage folders. I've tried several approaches, and it is creating new directories instead of saving the image in the correct directory, `storage/app/public/images/schools/logos/`.

In my filesystem config file, I have the following settings:

```
'disks' => [
        
        'public' => [
                'driver'     => 'local',
                'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
                'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
                'visibility' => 'public',
                'throw'      => false,
        ],
]
```

I've checked the permissions, and all are ok, even despite, wrongfully, it can create a new directory and store the image, yet not on the desired path (folder).

The directory structure in my `storage/` is the following:

I've tried to upload to `storage/app/public/images/schools/logos/` using the following line of code:

```
$filename = 'f032ec59-d568-4107-86d8-97fad7986273.png';
$request->file($type)->storeAs('public/images/schools/logos', $filename);
```

I presume something in the path is incorrect, but I can't figure it out despite several attempts. (I was used to storing in the `/public/images` but now moving things to `storage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#specifying-a-disk) method, you may pass the disk name as the third argument to the method:

```
$filename = 'f032ec59-d568-4107-86d8-97fad7986273.png';
$request->file($type)->storeAs('images/schools/logos', $filename, 'public')
```

Comment: Thank you @karl-hill for your help. I was not aware of the third argument. It's working! Thank you!!